# Remove column from OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an OpenCV Mat, and I would like to remove the first column. Is there a nice built-in way of removing specific columns from a matrix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Mat::col(int j)` method to get first column

```
    Mat m;
    Mat col1 = m.col(0)
```

Or, you can use `Mat::colRange(int startCol, int endCol)` to get original matrix without the first column:

```
    Mat noCol1 = m.colRange(1, m.cols)
```

Remember that the actual data is not copied, it is shared with the original matrix. to get copy of that value, you may use `Mat::clone()`.

More info: [Opencv 2.3 docmentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-col)